# How to take screenshot of specific subjectline (Gmail) email using Google Apps Script?

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail, screenshot

I am trying to get the screenshot of the (Gmail) email which has the specific subject line using google apps script into Google Sheets. I find a [source](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/a434b4ed50d91fe5f56fffcf6bcb3f78) that can get screenshots of the website. Here is the sample code:

```
var siteUrl = "### URL you want to retrieve a screenshot. ###";
var url ="https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v4/runPagespeed?screenshot=true&fields=screenshot&url=" +
encodeURIComponent(siteUrl);
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var obj = JSON.parse(res);
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(obj.screenshot.data),
  "image/png",
  "sample.png"
);
DriveApp.createFile(blob);
```

We can get the threads by using the following lines for the specific subjectline:

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"Daily Report"')
var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
```

But due to my novice skills, I am not able to stitch them up to get the screenshot of this specific subject line email. I wonder if there is a way to get around this. Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First, I apologize that my sample script was not useful for your situation. About your showing script, I updated it on December 9, 2021. Please be careful about this. But, unfortunately, in the current stage, the screenshot of a message from Gmail cannot be directly retrieved using "Method: pagespeedapi.runpagespeed". Because the URL of a message of Gmail cannot be publicly shared. So, in this case, it is required to use a workaround. But, I cannot imagine your expected result of `get the screenshot of the (Gmail) email`. For example, the screenshot you need is only the HTML body?

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes, I just want the screenshot of the interface which we see when we open any email.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I just want the screenshot of the interface which we see when we open any email.`, I think that in the current stage, this cannot be achieved because the URL of the Gmail message cannot be publicly shared. I apologize for this.

Comment: is there any workaround to this, because we are not sharing it publicly, we are just authorizing script using our personal email address for which we want screenshot

Comment: It seems that when "pagespeedapi.runpagespeed" is used, the URL is required to be a public link. But, the URL of Gmail is not a public link. By this, when my sample script is used with the URL of a Gmail message, the login screen is retrieved. So, I asked about my workaround. But, from `yes, I just want the screenshot of the interface which we see when we open any email.`, I understood that my workaround was not useful for your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Maybe we can look for another API apart from using pagespeed API

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when a workaround is used, what values do you want to include in the Email as an image?

Comment: `what values do you want to include in the Email as an image?`, we can include email subject line, and email body.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to export a message of Gmail using "pagespeedapi.runpagespeed" with Google Apps Script as an image.

#### Issue and workaround:

In the current stage, in order to use "pagespeedapi.runpagespeed", it is required to use the public link of the site. But, unfortunately, the URL of the message in Gmail is not a public link. By this, your goal cannot be directly achieved using "pagespeedapi.runpagespeed".

When I asked you about your required values in the Email as an image, you said `we can include email subject line, and email body.`. From this, in this answer, as a workaround, I would like to use the following flow.

1. Retrieve the subject and the HTML body from the Gmail message.
2. Convert the retrieved subject and HTML body to an image using `Charts.newTableChart()`.

When this flow is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
// This is from your showing script.
var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:"Daily Report"');
var msgs = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);

// I added the blow script.
var subject = msgs[0][0].getSubject();
var htmlBody = msgs[0][0].getBody();
var imageBlob = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(
  Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, '')
    .addRow([`<p style="font-size: 150%">Subject: ${subject}</p>`])
    .addRow([htmlBody])
    .build()
)
  .setOption('allowHtml', true)
  .setDimensions(1024, 1024)
  .build().getBlob();

// Here, the retrieved image is created as an image file in the root folder. By this, you can confirm the output image. The filename is "sample.png".
DriveApp.createFile(imageBlob.setName("sample.png"));
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the 1st message is used from `msgs` of your script.
- When this script is run, the 1st message is retrieved from `msgs`, and the subject and the HTML body are retrieved from the message. And then, those are converted to a PNG image as a blob. When you output the blob as an image file, you can see that the subject and the HTML body are shown in order.
- In this sample, the font size of the subject is 150%. Please modify this for your actual situation.
- In this sample, the image size is 1024 x 1024 as a sample size. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [newTableChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts#newtablechart)
- [newDataTable()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts#newdatatable)

Comment: Awesome, you are a legend. It works as intended. Thank you so much once again

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.